# Product of elements of a finite abelian group where at least two elements have order 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Disclaimer: This is a problem posed in Herstein that I've found one link where it was asked previously. However, it's been a year since I've taken algebra and wanted to type up a solution from notes I scribbled down because I found the problem interesting. This is a different solution to the problem and I wanted to see if it's a valid approach or if I've butchered some notation/terminology.

Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a finite abelian group under an arbitrary binary operator $\cdot$ where the set $G$ is defined as follows:

$$G=\{g_1,g_2,\cdots g_{n-1}, g_n\}$$

Question: Show that $g_1\cdot g_2\cdot\cdots g_{n-1}\cdot g_n=e$---where $e$ is the group identity element---if two or more elements of $G$ are of order two where $e$ is the group identity element.

Answer: First we aim to deconstruct $G$ into two sets $G=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are defined as follows:

$$A=\{g\in G: g^2\neq e\}$$
$$B=\{g\in G:g^2=e\}$$

Let $|A|=\alpha$ and $|B|=\beta$ where $\alpha+\beta=n$. First, we note that since $G$ is abelian, we may express the product of its elements as follows:

$$\prod_{g\in G} g=\prod_{g\in A}g\prod_{g\in B} g$$

Let's look at the product of elements in $A$. If no $a_i\in A$ are of order two, then $\forall\;a_i\in A,\exists\;a_j\in A:a_i\cdot a_j = e$ by the property of inverse elements of a group. Since $(G,\cdot)$ is abelian, $A$ under $\cdot$ must also be abelian, for $A\subseteq G$. This allows us to rearrange elements so that all elements are adjacent to their inverse in the product, which gives us the following:

$$\prod_{g\in A}g=\prod_{i=1}^{\alpha/2}e=e$$

Now we aim to look at the product of elements in $B$. Clearly $e\in B$ since $e^2=e$. However, we aim to explore nontrivial elements of $B$. We know there are at least two such elements as posed by the question. Suppose $B$ has two nontrivial elements $b_1,b_2\in B\subseteq G$. We claim that $b_1\cdot b_2$ is also an element of $B$. By the closure of $G$ under $\cdot$, we know that $b_1b_2\in G$. We know $b_1\cdot b_2$ is neither $b_1$ nor $b_2$ since neither are the identity element. Furthermore, we have that $b_1^2=b_2^2=e$ by construction. Since $G$ is abelian, we see that $(b_1b_2)^2=b_1^2\cdot b_2^2=e$, thus $b_1b_2$ is a unique element also in $B$.

To generalise, we note that upon including $e$, $|B|=\beta=2^k:k\in\mathbb N_0$. Amazingly, we may arbitrarily select $k$ nontrivial elements of $B$ to construct some generating set $\langle B\rangle$ of order $k$ whose arbitrary element products generate the set $B$ of order $2^k$. We see the arbitrary products of elements in $\langle B \rangle$ generate a set of order $2^k$ because $|S|=k\implies |\mathscr P(S)|=2^k$.

Similarly, we may see this from the binomial theorem:

$$\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}=2^k$$

Let's label elements of $\langle B\rangle$ as $b_i':i\in[1,k]\cap \mathbb N_1$.

Consider the set $\mathscr P(\langle B \rangle)=\{P_1, P_2, \cdots P_{2^k}\}$. For any possible combination of elements $b_i'$ in the generating set under $\cdot\;$, $\mathscr P(\langle B \rangle)$ contains exactly one set $P_i$ of elements involved in the product (as well as the empty set for the identity element). Now we may rewrite the product of elements in $B$ as the product of any possible product combination of elements in $\langle B\rangle$.

$$\prod_{g\in B}g=\prod_{i=1}^{2^k}\prod_{g\in P_i}g$$

We now aim to find how many times each element in $\langle B\rangle$ appears in this product. As a consequence of the binomial theorem, each element of $\langle B\rangle$ appears exactly $2^{k-1}$ times in the product. Since $G$ is abelian, we may once again rewrite the product as follows:

$$\prod_{g\in B}g=\prod_{g\in\langle B\rangle}g^{2^{k-1}}$$

Note that since all $g\in B$ are order two, any even power of each of its elements is the identity. We should also note that for $k=1$ we have an odd power of the lone nontrivial element of $B$, which the question specifically excludes. Whenever there are at least two nontrivial elements of order two, we get an even power of each element in the generating set, which gives us the desired result:

$$\prod_{g\in B}g=\prod_{g\in\langle B\rangle}g^{2^{k-1}}=e$$

Finally, upon combining, we see the following:

$$\prod_{g\in G} g=\prod_{g\in A}g\prod_{g\in B} g=e$$

Is this a valid approach to this problem that correctly uses notation/terminology without overlooking anything?

Comment: I took a quick look over this proof, and it looks good. However, it is **long**.

Comment: In particular, the $B$ part could be shortened by explcitly stating (what you implicitly use) that we are dealing with an $\Bbb F_2$ vector space. -- Alternatively, if $B_0\subset B$ is maximal with $B_0\cap b_1B_0=B_0\cap b_2B_0=B_0\cap b_1b_2B_0$, you could show that $B$ is the disjoint union of $B_0,b_1B_0,b_2B_0,b_1b_2B_0$ and then argue that $\prod_Bg=\prod_{B_0}g \cdot b_1^{|B_0|}\prod_{B_0}g\cdot  b_2^{|B_0|}\prod_{B_0}g\cdot  (b_1b_2)^{|B_0|}\prod_{B_0}g=\prod_{B_0}g^4\cdot b_1^{2|B_0|}\cdot b_2^{2|B_0|}=e$

Comment: I think the shortest and simplest proof of the $B$ part is to note that multiplying by $b_1$ is a self-inverse bijection of $B$ (not a homomorphism, just a function), and we can therefore partition $B$ into pairs $\{b_i,b_1b_i\}$. The product of the two elements of any pair is $b_1$, and there are an even number of pairs.